# Get next direction instruction while navigating Google Maps, OSM etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, openstreetmap, directions

I was wondering if anyone had any experience using the Google Maps directions API or if something similar exists for free in Open Street Maps or similar to provide the next navigation instruction.
For example if i need to take a the 3rd exit in 500m, is it possible to get that object?
I am currently looking at using the Google Maps Directions API as a test using ASP.net with a JS map.
Thanks

Comment: You might be looking for the [step instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#:~:text=the%20following%20fields%3A-,instructions,-contains%20instructions%20for) of Google Maps Platform Directions API. As you see, Directions API has [DirectionsLeg](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#:~:text=currency%20specified%20above.-,Directions%20Legs,-Note%3A%20The%20legacy) object and each  DirectionsLeg has an array of DirectionsStep object that contains instructions for each step.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i was looking into that and their instructions. I wondered how to get a hold of the next instruction that will be displayed while navigating. But i will check it out in more detail.